# onSubmit form - Ajax request to validate the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, forms

I have this scenario where when submiting html form we call javascript method to validate the form. Problem is that validation is done through Ajax request calling php function which returns json array which is empty or contains array with errors.

I am using Ajax request as this `newValidation` function will be used on all forms on my application so all field ids names and stuff is dynamic same as validation messages.

Console log results are:

```
Undifiend
```

It should be `True` or `False`.

So it looks like `.done` run after console.log.

I thought .done is waiting until ajax is finished and only then proceed?

Reason why I am asking I need this .done to run first so it can assing answer variable and only then return boolean to the form. Does this even possible?

**UPDATED:**

**Html form:**

```
<form id="systemManagementSettings" action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return newValidation('systemManagementSettings')">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function newValidation(formId){
var answer;
var $inputs = $('#'+formId+' :input');
    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {           
            values[this.id] = $(this).val();
            $( "div#"+this.id+"_validation" ).text("");
    });

var FinalValidation = $.ajax({
    url: "validation/getValidationData",
    type: "POST",
    data: {form: formId, values: values},

});
FinalValidation.done(function(data){
    var resultArray = JSON.parse(data);

    if($.isEmptyObject(resultArray))
    {
        answer = true;                      
    }
    else
    {
        $.each( resultArray, function( key, value ) {               
            $( "div#"+key+"_validation" ).text(value);              
        });
        answer = false;
    }
});

console.log(answer);    

return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you prevent the form from actually being submitted?
Use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

**UPDATE**

Submit the form in the `done` function.

```
function newValidation(formId){
    var answer;
    var $inputs = $('#'+formId+' :input');
        var values = {};
        $inputs.each(function() {           
            values[this.id] = $(this).val();
            $( "div#"+this.id+"_validation" ).text("");
        });

    var FinalValidation = $.ajax({
        url: "validation/getValidationData",
        type: "POST",
        data: {form: formId, values: values},
    });

    FinalValidation.done(function(data){
        var resultArray = JSON.parse(data);

        if($.isEmptyObject(resultArray))
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: $('#'+formId).attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data: {form: $('#'+formId).serializeArray()},
            });                      
        }
        else
        {
            $.each( resultArray, function( key, value ) {               
                $( "div#"+key+"_validation" ).text(value);              
            });
        }
    }); 

    return false; //all the time
}
```

Comment: on the function last tile 'return false'

Comment: this is why i need to set answer to true or false on .done and only then proceed

Comment: Oh, I see now. Please edit your code to include the last curly `}`. I thought `return false` was outside the newValidation function. First of all, you have some issues with defining variables multiple times, you define `dt` and `time` in each conditional. They should just be defined once in a function, preferably at the top. I tried to replicate your code [here](http://jsbin.com/zucadahili/1/edit?html,js,console,output) and it looks like it's working. Are you sure your AJAX response is correct?

Comment: You can ignore time thing its there only for testing purpose it won be there

Comment: `done` will run whenever the request is resolved, see [deffered.done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), so you can't make sure it will 'run first'. Maybe I am not getting why it is a problem, why don't you return `answer` inside the `done` block?

Comment: Maybe you are making a confusion about what 'onsubmit' does. It's just an event that will be fired when you send the form. What do you expect it to do by returning a value? You should look at [this example](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/)

Comment: Ok so the structure I have is this:
1) User submits the form.
2) onSubmit we call function which should return true or false
3) If its true the form continues and post all data to action if no its stops leaving messages where needed.

Comment: Yes onSubmit is event which allows to prenevent form to be submitted depending on the value is returned. So lets say if i return false form will not be subbmitted if  i return true then form will post all data to action

Comment: And i cannot use example you provided because all form id from are generated from xml file. And if i change form id or add new input field I will get errors. So then i have to update js file. which is not possible so the function should be dynamic and js file cannot have any static form ids specified

Comment: You need to return false all the time (therefore not submit by default). In the `done` function if the response has errors display them, else you submit the form manually. You can use form.submit() for that. In your case, it will be `$('#'+formId).submit()`. Updated the answer.

Comment: if we add this .submit when we will call same function and we will end up in a loop if there is no errors.

Comment: Then you can make a different ajax request instead of using .submit(), updated answer again